# Get the details of one IAsset from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm getting to grips with Azure, specifically Media Services.

I want to collect the details of one media item I've uploaded and encoded in Media Services without downloading the entire AssetBaseCollection from Azure.

When I have 1000's of assets, I worry this is not the best way to do it but currently this is the only way I can access any asset details as below.

```
var assetList = _context.Assets.ToList();
```

If I try and query _context.Assets directly (single, firstordefault) I get an unsupported exception.

How can I collect only one asset (IAsset) from _context.Assets without pulling the entire collection and performing the query on the list instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the assets, but you have to first use the `.Where(predicate bool)`, and then `.FirstOrDefault`.

Following code will get you only one asset without getting all of them into a list:

```
 public IAsset GetAssetById(string assetId)
        {
            var asset = _context.Assets.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(assetId)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (null == asset)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return asset;
        }
```

You can check rest of my code at the [WaMediaWeb project](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb), where I've wrapped in a Web Application almost everything you could do with Media Service.

Comment: Ah, right. Thank you. I'll checkout you project, I'm also struggling with Asset.Publish which I understand is deprecated.